# Show popup at mouse location

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show usercontrol as popup at mouse location.

However below code doesn't work for this;

```
            System.Drawing.Point mousePos = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
            System.Drawing.Point formPos = this.Bounds.Location;
            popupChart1.ultraLabel1.Text = e.DataRow.ToString() ;
            popupChart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(mousePos.X - formPos.X, mousePos.Y - formPos.Y);
            popupChart1.Show();
```

It doesn't throws any error, it just show it self at another place. What could be the reason ?

Comment: The problem is the `formPos`, the `Bounds.Location` is probably returning (0,0), you should use the actual position properties like `this.Left` and `this.Top`.

Comment: @RonBeyer Its also didn't work.

Comment: I see the other problem, the `popupChart.Location` is in local coordinates and you are setting it as screen coordinates. You need to translate the point back to local (client) coordinates. See [Control.PointToClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @RonBeyer I also tried like this and didn't work; popupChart1.Location = this.PointToClient(new System.Drawing.Point(mousePos.X - formPos.X, mousePos.Y - formPos.Y));

Comment: Don't try to subtract formPos from mousePos to convert to client coordinates yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by popup? `ContextMenuStrip` or `Form`?

Answer (score 3):

You should set the location after the form is rendered.

And if you want it to show at your mouse cursor position then simply use `Cursor.Position` instead of the math you did

```
popupChart1.Show();
popupChart1.Location = Cursor.Position;
```

OR
if you want to set the location before you show the window you can do

```
popupChart1.Location = Cursor.Position;
popupChart1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
popupChart1.Show();
```